# How to Send a logout message from Java REST servlet to angular Client?

Tags: java, angular, rest, websocket

I have some doubts about how to send a message from a Java Rest Server, to an Angular Client. I have read about WebSockets, but Im not sure if it suits what im looking for.

We use a token-based authentication , and when a client logouts, we choosed to simply remove token from client. Until here everything is correct. Problem is that our system includes a functionality that allows admins to logoff online users. As clients can't notice that they where logged off, they can't remove token. I'm looking for a way to send a message from server to an specific client, so It can logouts from ClientSide, and remove its token.

Is WebSocket best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do. When a user is logged off, which can actually also happen when the session expires, nothing will happen until the user performs an action. This action might require a backend call which can then return a 401 html code.

When you really immediately want to redirect the user to a login page, you might indeed need web-sockets or if that is not an option, hit your backend with a certain interval to validate the session